# How can I get gevent-py2.7-win64.egg

Tags: python, gevent

I'm new for python. How can I get gevent-py2.7-win64.egg, my system is win32, and I need a 64bit module of gevent

Comment: 64bit libraries only work on 64bit OS.

Comment: I meant I can't find gevent-py2.7-win64.egg on the internet, I wonder where can I get gevent-py2.7-win64.egg and I don't need to build or install myself

Comment: If you have 32bit OS, you can't use 64bit libraries

Answer (score 1):

Please get a windows installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

if your are using virtualenv,

> 1. install gevent directly by exe file
> 2. copy the generated files like ***gevent-0.13.8-py2.7.egg-info, gevent*** in your ***%PYTHON_HOME%\Lib\site-packages*** to your %VIRTUALENV%\Lib\site-packages directory, like ***D:\Dev\python\Envs\gotcha\Lib\site-packages***

There you go! All done!
Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

first test cmd easy_install gevent
if failed, just go google python setuptools and then installed it and easy_install gevent 
just let the setuptools to help you choose the suitable module

Comment: I meant I can't find gevent-py2.7-win64.egg on the internet, I wonder where can I get gevent-py2.7-win64.egg and I don't need to build or install myself